# python Itertools.combination unable to display certain combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I tried using python itertools.combinations_with_replacement to show all possible combinations in the list[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0] with r=6 and i noticed that a particular number 345769 wasn’t found....can anyone tell me the reason for that cause I’m lost

Answer (score 2):

`combinations` produces unique combinations disregarding order, but the outputs are ordered based on the input; all the outputs will be some subset of the input in the same order they appeared in the input. So you wouldn't ever get `3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 9` because `7` comes after `6` in the input. You *would* see `3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9` (`6` and `7` occur in input order). If you want to see both, use `permutations`, not `combinations`.